# User specific setting in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, global-variables

I am developing a Ruby on Rails application. In my app I have a setting on the welcome page where user can select the language (by default is English). Where should I declare this variable and where should I change it from default once the user changes it?

I tried declaring a config variable in development.rb, but since it is global for the applicaition, if user A changes the language, user B will also see the changes done by user A.

I need a setting which is user specific. In other words: one session specific. When I open the website it should initialize to the default and when I change it, the application should not apply those changes to others.

Answer (score 0):

If you "need a setting which is user specific" you could define a session variable:

`session[:language]`